# Firefox Webextensions: Modify HTML before Browser parsing

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a Firefox extension.
When a *new page* is loaded, I need to modify the **main HTML** **AFTER** it has been downloaded, but **BEFORE** it's parsed by the browser.

If it's not clear what I'm saying, look at the accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795438/load-and-execution-sequence-of-a-web-page) question; After *step 1*, before *step 2*.

What JavaScript WebExtension API Event can I use to accomplish this?

Please note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803115/how-to-preprocess-html-before-its-loaded-and-parsed-by-mozilla) question does NOT answer my question as **gBrowser** is depreciated.

Comment: If you tell us what you would use it for, maybe we can come up with a solution for that specific problem. And why is later in the event flow not an option?

Comment: Smile4ever I want to replace certain includes(ie. script/link tags) with others, before they are loaded.

Comment: Redirect the requests using webRequest to the new URLs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest